# Visual Studio doesn't create start files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I've just installed VS on a new machine & when creating a new project, none of the starting files are created. For instance when making an ASP.NET web app I just get left with a completely empty solution & when making a console app I get the starting code, but the project can't start because it's made outside of the solution... I guess...

I've tried reinstalling VS but no difference.

[image: 1]

Comment: Looks like you are creating console apps.

Comment: Yes, I posted an example image of how things look like when I create a new console app

Comment: I don't think we have enough information.  What does the screen look like when you go create a web project?  Do you get a list of templates to choose from?

Comment: No I'm actually missing that last step that I think should be there...example... Create new project-->ASP.NET Core Web App-->Configure your new project-->Additional information-->Create   ....And there's no last screen where I could pick a fresh template..example template... And I've just noticed opening old solutions doesn't work either https://prnt.sc/1r4vzgu

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, I see that this issue appeared on .NET/.NET Core projects. So have you tried to create a project which is based on .NET Framework and see if it works for .NET Framework project?

“Error: The project file cannot be opened. Unable to locate the .NET SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json …”, it seems many causes for this error, but the key is unable to locate the .NET SDK.
So two mainly aspects: `installation` and `path`.

1). Navigate to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk and check if there lists different versions of SDK folders. Also type `dotnet --list-sdks` in CMD to make sure that all installed versions of dotnet SDK are listed. If there is no SDK listed, or some are missing, try to reinstall them.

2). Check the environment variable. Go to This PC(right-click) > Properties > Advanced system settings > Advanced > Environment Variables > System Variables > find Path > click Edit, and check if `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` path is configured there. If not, try to add it and restart VS.

3). Other suggestions: try to install x86 version of SDK, repair Visual Studio, and refer to this similar thread: [Visual Studio 2019 unable to locate .NET Core SDK](https://superuser.com/questions/1431833/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-locate-net-core-sdk).